# printing the output for each line from a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to print the encrypted version of each line read from the file */tmp/values.txt*.  Can anyone please help me with the logic?  Below is my code:

```
with open ('/tmp/values.txt') as f:
    sentence = f.readlines()
    for sent in sentence:
        crypt,key = [ x for x in sent.rstrip().split('|')]
        key = key.strip().split(' ')
        key = list(map(int , key))
        new_keys = [  (x-1)  for x in key]
        op = [crypt[new_keys[keys]] for keys in range(0,len(new_keys))]
        print (''.join(op))
```

/tmp/values.txt :

```
  Ta1HN9UPlxLfsYzEIAR4GcJQvh5biMW7oun0S8Keq6tDZmkVjX3FgB2yCwrOd p| 18 9 40 10 2 35 61 40 59 62 8 34 13 26 47 29 35 62 3 32 6 6
  7NZq8pegmhAnBKH4VrGQdbPFw35jaUCzOS10oyLiv6IMXJW2 ksDRTfucElYxt9| 47 40 59 59 40 29 9 49 34 10 29 50 7 51 6 7 29 18 7 49 35 27 42 16
  6qcAdESB7tlep9suiyOv8zXFg24TkaZxKLbhRUMjC3GHrI5o 10QPmVJfYWDNnw| 34 12 63 17 15 49 41 30 45 45 48 11 11 49 50 21 42 26
```

Comment: you have wrong indentions

Comment: It would be helpful to the reader if you explained what is actually not working in your code. What is happening that does not meet your expectations? Ultimately, you are looking to put together a [mcve] that will help the reader quickly understand your problem

Comment: with correct indentions it works for me. I was not sure if lines in file start with two spaces or it is only mistake so I used `strip()` instead of `rstrip()`. Result: "Alexander Pushkin 1799 William Shakespeare 1564 Lewis Carroll 1832"

Comment: @furas, that's the problem, all right.  You might write that up as an answer, now that I've fixed the indentation.  Good catch.  With **rstrip**, the output is just more character soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if lines in file start with two spaces or it is only mistake so I used `strip()` instead of `rstrip()` and now (with correct indentions) it works for me.

```
with open ('/tmp/values.txt') as f:
    sentence = f.readlines()
    for sent in sentence:
        crypt,key = [ x for x in sent.rstrip().split('|')]
        key = key.strip().split(' ')
        key = list(map(int , key))
        new_keys = [  (x-1)  for x in key]
        op = [crypt[new_keys[keys]] for keys in range(0,len(new_keys))]
        print (''.join(op))
```

For test I made this version using string instead of file:

```
data = '''  Ta1HN9UPlxLfsYzEIAR4GcJQvh5biMW7oun0S8Keq6tDZmkVjX3FgB2yCwrOd p| 18 9 40 10 2 35 61 40 59 62 8 34 13 26 47 29 35 62 3 32 6 6
  7NZq8pegmhAnBKH4VrGQdbPFw35jaUCzOS10oyLiv6IMXJW2 ksDRTfucElYxt9| 47 40 59 59 40 29 9 49 34 10 29 50 7 51 6 7 29 18 7 49 35 27 42 16
  6qcAdESB7tlep9suiyOv8zXFg24TkaZxKLbhRUMjC3GHrI5o 10QPmVJfYWDNnw| 34 12 63 17 15 49 41 30 45 45 48 11 11 49 50 21 42 26'''

for sent in data.split('\n'):
    crypt,key = [ x for x in sent.strip().split('|')]
    key = key.strip().split(' ')
    key = list(map(int , key))
    new_keys = [  (x-1)  for x in key]
    op = [crypt[new_keys[keys]] for keys in range(0,len(new_keys))]
    print (''.join(op))
```

After some small modifications I get:

```
data = '''  Ta1HN9UPlxLfsYzEIAR4GcJQvh5biMW7oun0S8Keq6tDZmkVjX3FgB2yCwrOd p| 18 9 40 10 2 35 61 40 59 62 8 34 13 26 47 29 35 62 3 32 6 6
  7NZq8pegmhAnBKH4VrGQdbPFw35jaUCzOS10oyLiv6IMXJW2 ksDRTfucElYxt9| 47 40 59 59 40 29 9 49 34 10 29 50 7 51 6 7 29 18 7 49 35 27 42 16
  6qcAdESB7tlep9suiyOv8zXFg24TkaZxKLbhRUMjC3GHrI5o 10QPmVJfYWDNnw| 34 12 63 17 15 49 41 30 45 45 48 11 11 49 50 21 42 26'''

for sent in data.split('\n'):
    crypt, keys = sent.strip().split('|')
    keys = keys.strip().split(' ')
    keys = [int(x)-1 for x in keys]
    op = [crypt[x] for x in keys]
    print(''.join(op))
```

Result:

```
Alexander Pushkin 1799
William Shakespeare 1564
Lewis Carroll 1832
```